# Stacked picture with hover and tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, html

On github under notifications there are avatars of the involved people. On hover the picture can all be shown.
I want this but I don't find it and I don't have the first step to do that.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

so i wil not show you some code but i tell you what i would do:

- create the tooltip markup with a Style containing the display: none
- add a data-id to the tooltip-markup and the img
- appand the marup to the body
- calculate the left and top position of the element you will hover
- add the position to the tooltip
- add to the img a hover-event in wich you read the data-id find the tooltip with the same data-id and set the visibility to block